# Ubuntu EC2 instance Mysql Database Issue

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have a ubuntu ec2 micro instance where I have setted up LAMP environment with mysql/phpmyadmin as well. However, my application in every few days getting 'database connectivity issue' and when I reboot the instance, it gets back normal.

When I login to terminal in such situation I can see a message as below:

```
*** /dev/xvda1 will be checked for errors at next reboot ***
```

Do anyone have any idea why this is happening and what I can do to avoid such problem? Thanks.

Comment: Look at your logs to find out what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Every time somebody logs in the pam_motd module runs all the scripts in `/etc/update-motd.d/`. One of these scripts is `98-fsck-at-reboot` which runs `/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-fsck-at-reboot`. In essence this script, for each ext filesystem, checks the mount count against the maximal mount count and the last fsck against the check interval to determine if a filesystem needs to be fscked, and, if so, outputs text that gets added to `/etc/motd`

When a system boots, upstart examines `/etc/init/mountall.conf` and runs `mountall`, which runs fsck on the filesystems if the conditions stated in the previous paragraph are met.

As you can see these goings-on are not triggered by detected errors and so probably have nothing to do with your database connectivity issues.

Most likely you are exhausting a resource (I'm guessing memory) on your micro instance and a reboot causes resource consumption to be reset. If you don't wish to troubleshoot it any further I'd upgrade to at least a small instance.